# Bedeutung von "abdecken" im Kontext

Tags: meaning

Transkription

Die Sportler  müssen insgesamt 20 Module studieren. Davon sind Zehn Module Pflicht: **Die** **decken** so diesen grundlegenden BWL-Bereich **ab**. Und alles, was darüber hinausgeht, sind 10 weitere Wahlpflichtmodule.

Aussage: Die Studierenden konzentrieren sich auf die Grundlagen des Faches BWL.

Das ist falsch.

Das ist ein Hörproblem. Dazu habe ich eine Frage.

Was bedeutet "abdecken"? Die Sportler studieren nur einfach Grundlagen des Faches BWL, aber konzentrieren sich nicht darauf? Oder ersetzt das Pflichtmodul die Grundlagen?

Comment: "The athlets have to do 20 modules. 10 of those are obligatory: They cover the basic parts of an MBA. Everything else, going beyond that, are 10 modules of choice".

Comment: "Das ist falsch." Ist das die Lösung der Übung?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In diesem Zusammenhang wird "abdecken" im übertragenen Sinn gebraucht, die Bedeutung kommt einer der wörtlichen Bedeutungen aber ziemlich nahe.

Eine der wörtlichen Bedeutungen von "etwas abdecken" ist ja "etwas mit einer Abdeckung versehen" (oft zum Schutz), "etwas über etwas ausbreiten".

> Er deckt den Teppich mit einer Folie ab, damit keine Fußabdrücke auf den Teppich kommen.

> Wenn Ihr die Möbel in den Keller stellt, deckt sie bitte mit den Tüchern ab, damit sie nicht einstauben.

Im übertragenen Sinn kann man "abdecken" verwenden, wenn etwas einen Zeitabschnitt, einen Bedarf, eine Anforderung oder etwas ähnliches erfüllt.

> Für Montag bis Mittwoch haben wir genügend Mitarbeiter. Wenn wir auch Donnerstag und Freitag abdecken wollen, müssen wir zusätzliche Mitarbeiter einstellen.

> Die Firma deckt mit ihren Produkten den gesamten europäischen Markt ab.

> Diese Aufgaben kann die neue Mitarbeiterin, Frau Müller, abdecken. Sie hat die dazu nötige Expertise.

> Die Einnahmen aus diesem Projekt decken die Ausgaben nicht ab, wir machen damit Verlust.

In Kontext Deines Beispiels muss ein Student zwanzig Module studieren. Von diesen zwanzig Modulen sind zehn Pflichtmodule, hier können die Studenten also nicht wählen. Die anderen zehn Module sind Wahlpflichtmodule. Das heißt, die Studenten können (aus einem bestimmten Angebot an Modulen) wählen, aber sie müssen zehn Module wählen (deshalb "Pflicht").

Die zehn Pflichtmodule *decken den grundlegenden BWL-Bereich ab*. Das heißt, die zehn Pflichtmodule umfassen die Grundlagen der BWL (vollständig). In diesen Modulen lernen die Studenten die Grundlagen der BWL, und damit haben sie diesen Bereich *abgedeckt*. Die restlichen zehn Module befassen sich offenbar mit anderen Themen.

Als Anmerkung am Rande, "abdecken" ist ein sogenanntes [Januswort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Januswort). Das heißt, neben der oben erwähnten Bedeutung "etwas mit einer Abdeckung versehen" kann "abdecken" auch heißen, "eine Abdeckung entfernen":

> Der Sturm hat das Dach abgedeckt.

> Das dreckige Geschirr vom Mittagessen steht noch auf dem Tisch, deckst Du bitte den Tisch ab? (*Räumst Du bitte das dreckige Geschirr weg?*)

> Das Schwimmbecken war mit einer Plane abgedeckt. Ich habe es abgedeckt (*hier: die Plane entfernt*), wir können also schwimmen gehen.

Die weitere Bedeutung "ein totes Tier fachgerecht zerlegen und verwerten (insbesondere enthäuten)" kommt im Alltag nicht häufig vor.

Comment: Die Bedeutung ist mehrdeutig und die Antwort von der Frage "Konzentration" ist falsch?

Comment: @Kim Das Verb "abdecken" kann verschiedene Bedeutungen ausdrücken. Es wird aber normalerweise aus dem Kontext klar, welche Bedeutung gemeint ist. Das ist auch in diesem Fall so. Es ergibt keinen Sinn, in "die Pflichtmodule decken die Grundlagen der BWL ab" das Verb "abdecken" als "eine Abdeckung entfernen" zu verstehen. Es ergibt aber Sinn (und wird auch oft so verwendet), "abdecken" hier als "etwas über etwas ausbreiten" zu verstehen, eben im übertragenen Sinn.

Comment: @Kim Zum Thema Konzentration: Wenn die Hälfte der Studieninhalte (zehn von zwanzig Modulen) sich mit dem Thema BWL beschäftigen, kann man daraus schließen, dass sich die Studenten auf BWL konzentrieren. Das ist aber nicht die Bedeutung von "die Pflichtmodule decken die Grundlagen der BWL ab". Vielleicht hilft es, an das recht ähnliche englische Verb "to cover" zu denken: "The obligatory modules cover the basics of business administration (BWL)".

Comment: Die Antwort geht nicht darauf ein, inwiefern die Bedeutung des Wortes *abdecken* die Aussage mit *konzentrieren* wahr oder falsch macht. Die wörtliche Bedeutung von *abdecken* spielt bei der Beantwortung der Frage keine Rolle.

Comment: @DavidVogt In der Frage steht wörtlich "Was bedeutet 'abdecken'?? ". Das Verb wird in diesem Beispiel im übertragenen Sinn verwendet. Diese übertragene Bedeutung lässt sich gut verstehen, wenn man eine der wörtlichen Bedeutungen als Grundlage nimmt. Deshalb habe ich diese wörtliche Bedeutung erklärt, und dann den Schritt zur übertragenen Bedeutung gemacht. Außerdem habe ich, als Nebenbemerkung, weitere Bedeutungen von "abdecken" angesprochen. Dass die ursprüngliche Fehlinterpretation mit Bezug auf "konzentrieren" nicht korrekt ist, hielt ich nach meiner Erläuterung für offenkundig.

Comment: danke für Ihre Antwort

Comment: @kim dann solltest du sie mit +1 bewerten.

Answer (score -1):

Weil andere Leute schon die Bedeutung von "abdecken" ausführlich erklärt haben, würde ich nur über die Lösung schreiben.

Ich glaube, das, was Sie "Hörproblem" genannt haben, ist eine Aufgabe des Hörverstehens einer Deutschprüfung. Da hört man einen Hörtext und muss bei mehreren Aussagen in einem Kästchen für Falsch oder Richtig ankreuzen, nicht wahr?

Die Aussage, die Sie erwähnt haben, war laut des Lösungsbogens falsch. Aber Sie sind nicht ganz einverstanden damit, glaube ich. Ich kann Sie nachvollziehen.

Ich bin der Meinung, dass man aus dem Hörtext nicht schließen kann, ob die **Studierenden** sich auf Grundlagen der BWL konzentrieren oder nicht. Im Hörtext wurde lediglich angegeben, dass die **Sportler** 10 Pflichtmodule studieren müssen, welche den grundlegenden Bereich der BWL abdecken.

Erstens, man kann nicht eindeutig wissen, ob die Studierenden sich auf die BWL-Grundlage konzentrieren, oder auf andere Bereiche der anderen Fächer, die möglicherweise auch in Pflichtmodulen eingeschlossen wären, oder eher auf andere 10 Wahlpflichtmodule.

Zweitens, ich kann nicht wissen, ob die **Studierende** die **Sportler** bedeuten. Um das zu wissen, müsste ich den gesamten Hörtext lesen.

Manchmal haben solche Aufgaben drei Antwortmöglichkeiten: Richtig, Falsch und „der Text sagt nichts dazu“ bzw. „kann nicht wissen“ oder etwas Ähnliches. Wenn die von Ihnen genannte Aufgabe auch so eine Antwortoption hätte, hätte ich die ausgewählt. Aber wenn nur „richtig“ oder „falsch“ möglich gewesen wären, hätte ich „falsch“ ausgewählt, weil ich sicherlich nicht wissen kann, ob die Aussage richtig ist, obwohl ich auch nicht weiß, ob die Aussage wirklich falsch ist.